# KVM debian wheezy packages with ceph support

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ceph

Does anybody know any packages out there for kvm which are compiled with RBD support?

I have these installed right now:

```
ii  kvm                              1:1.1.2+dfsg-6+deb7u8         amd64        dummy transitional package from kvm to qemu-kvm
ii  qemu-kvm                         1.1.2+dfsg-6+deb7u8           amd64        Full virtualization on x86 hardware
ii  libvirt-bin                      1.2.9-9~bpo70+1               amd64        programs for the libvirt library
ii  libvirt-clients                  1.2.9-9~bpo70+1               amd64        programs for the libvirt library
ii  libvirt-daemon                   1.2.9-9~bpo70+1               amd64        programs for the libvirt library
ii  libvirt-daemon-system            1.2.9-9~bpo70+1               amd64        Libvirt daemon configuration files
ii  libvirt0                         1.2.9-9~bpo70+1               amd64        library for interfacing with different virtualization systems
ii  python-libvirt                   1.2.1-2~bpo70+1               amd64        libvirt Python bindings
```

Building kvm on my own seems to be very difficult since it has many dependencies including gui libraries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

qemu, libvirt and virt-manager support RBD on Fedora.

Interestingly I did *not* see support on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run rbd block devices with kvm, you need to check out whether the emulator qemu has the support of ceph or not.

To do this, first check qemu-kvm:

```
$ sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=?
Supported formats: vvfat vpc vmdk vhdx vdi sheepdog sheepdog sheepdog rbd raw host_cdrom host_floppy host_device file qed qcow2 qcow parallels nbd nbd nbd dmg tftp ftps ftp https http cow cloop bochs blkverify blkdebug
```

And look for rbd in the output.

Then check qemu-utils:

```
$ qemu-img -h
Supported formats: vvfat vpc vmdk vhdx vdi sheepdog sheepdog sheepdog rbd raw host_cdrom host_floppy host_device file qed qcow2 qcow parallels nbd nbd nbd dmg tftp ftps ftp https http cow cloop bochs blkverify blkdebug
```

And look for rbd in the output.

If rbd is not there, what you can do is to build qemu from source with rbd support enabled

```
git clone git://git.qemu.org/qemu.git
cd qemu
./configure --enable-rbd
make; make install
```